# Domino Designer - send an email notification with the preview of the saved form

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript, lotus, lotus-formula

I have a survey that will rate the "Seller" regarding the "Performance" and "Improvement". I need to send an email notification together with an actual copy of my rating. What command can I use?

Attached is the screen capture of the actual survey. In that example, Janine must be able to see through email my rating for her.

[Survey](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mxDiR.png)

Answer (score 1):

You could create a separate Form defined "On Create: Inherit entire selected document into richtext field / as  rich text".

when your survey is open, compose this form, copy the Rich Text content and put it in a mail.

You can also design this form to be mail ready (call the Rich Text Body, add the sendto field...)

Comment: Apologies but I am new with Domino Designer. I cannot follow with the instruction given. WIll this work for every seller that I will rate?

Comment: See here: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSVRGU_8.5.3/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_CREATING_A_FIELD_THAT_INHERITS_AN_ENTIRE_DOCUMENT.html

But the first thing you need to do is learn how to send email messages. Here's a tutorial. https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSVRGU_8.5.3/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_LESSON_3_SENDING_AN_EMAIL_MESSAGE.html

Comment: Will it require Lotus Script? how about if I try to use @mailsend command? WIll there be a difference?

Comment: @MailSend( sendTo ; copyTo ; blindCopyTo ; subject ; remark ; bodyFields ; [ flags ] ) do not accept a rich text item, so you can't send a "screen shot" of youyr survey

Comment: You may try using @mailSend in the postopen of the custom form. I think it's possible to do the whole process without any line of lotusscript. BUT you must know how to design a form.

Comment: Emmanuel, I tried to use @mailsend command, however, I cannot send an exact copy of my saved "Survey Form". And I have to automatically use this command everytime I will save a survey. I think the problem is how can I copy the Survey Form into a Rich Text or any possible. Apologies but I am really new with Domino Designer and I cannot follow with the instruction on help. Can you give me a more detailed instruction. Thanks.

Comment: If you use Mailsend correctly, you absolutely can send an exact copy. But comment threads on StackOverflow are not the place for detailed instruction. If mailsend is not doing what you expect, then the thing to do is post another question. Give it a title like "How do I get Lotus Notes @MailSend to send an exact copy of my form?"  Show your code in the question. Show your form, too. Tell us what you expect to happen. Tell us what actually happens. Also, re "I am new to Domino Designer": You need to find yourself a good book or some web-based courses. It will help you ask better questions.

Comment: @LouisKennethDorado, did you create in your application a new form with one Rich text field  called body? In this form, in the form properties (alt+enter) did you  defined "On Create: Inherit entire selected document into richtext field / as rich text"